# Something sells well

Tags: phrase-usage

It is always said:

> Air conditioners **sell well** in the summer months.

Could **are sold well** be used here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Air conditioners sell well in the summer months.
>
> Air conditioners are sold well in the summer months.

Those two sentences have slightly different meanings. "air conditioners sell (adverb)" describes if they are selling. "air conditioners are sold (adverb)" describes the skills of the person selling them, or the method they are using to do the selling.

With that said, "Air conditioners are sold well in the summer months" does not work. You could say "Air conditioners are sold well by the sales team", although it sounds a little constructed. You would probably want to use a present voice construction. "Our sales team does a great job of selling air conditioners during the summer."

Comment: But the sentence "air conditioners sell well" sounds like "air conditioner" is a live object and it's selling something that is not mentioned here. "Air conditioners are sold well" sounds like somebody is selling air conditioners well. Am I missing something/ Please explain to me.

Comment: @Man_From_India *Sell* in "air conditioners sell well" is intransitive.  It has a different meaning than transitive *sell* in "he sells air conditioners".  The passive is based on the latter, not the former, so the answer here is no.

Comment: You could say "Air conditioners *have* sold well in the summer months." indicating past results and an expectation of current and (possibly) future results.